# How to make Html.DisplayFor display HTML I read from the DB?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using a CKEditor on my MVC project. I'm saving HTML into the DB.
WHen I read it and display it on screen, what I get is

```
   &lt;p&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.cnh.com"&gt;www.cnh.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt; &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I use Html.DisplayFor.

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SampleCollectionInstructions)
</td>
```

How can I make it display the links properly and one per line??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `Raw method` to return markup without html encoded
Ex;

```
@Html.Raw("<div>Some text</div>")
```

Comment: I used   @Html.Raw(item.SampleCollectionInstructions) and it worked. Tks

Answer (score 6):

If anyone else is confused about doing this in loops, like I was:

You can just omit both **DisplayFor** and **modelItem =>**,  so:

```
@Html.Raw(item.SampleCollectionInstructions)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Item.APPTXT))
```